# What is the meaning of the shaking image in all the Symphogear XV preview image sets?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

On the day before each episode of Symphogear XV airs, a new set of preview pictures are released on the [Symphogear XV website](https://symphogear-xv.com/). Amongst each set of pictures, there's always exactly one picture that shakes when you hover your mouse over it.

Listed below:

- [Episode 1](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext01.php): Maria & Hibiki (3rd image)
- [Episode 2](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext02.php): Kirika (4th image)
- [Episode 3](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext03.php): Hibiki vs. Millaarc (4th image)
- [Episode 4](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext04.php): Flustered Bikki (5th image)
- [Episode 5](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext05.php): Tsubasa (2nd image)
- [Episode 6](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext06.php): Ogawa driving (6th image)
- [Episode 7](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext07.php): Elfnein (1st image)
- [Episode 8](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext08.php): Château de Tiffauges (6th image)
- [Episode 9](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext09.php): Fudou (7th image)
- [Episode 10](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext10.php): Bikki waist tape measure (7th image)
- [Episode 11](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext11.php): Millaarc kick (8th image)
- [Episode 12](https://symphogear-xv.com/next/XVnext12.php): Yggdrasil (2nd image)

I was wondering, is there any significance behind these particular picture choices? Or were they just chosen arbitrarily?

Comment: Apparently has been a tradition since [Symphogear G](https://www.symphogear-g.com/story/next01.php), [GX](https://www.symphogear-gx.com/next/GXnext01.php), [AXV](https://www.symphogear-axz.com/next/AXZnext01.php) (but not the first [Symphogear](http://www.symphogear.com/next2.html)).